# I need the box component inside my section component to be full width

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, box

So in the picture you can see how my code looks. Im using mui components. I have this section and inside i have this box with the nav filter links. The red part is the section, while the white inside is my nav link bar. I want this box to get the full width of the section, but I dont know what I do
wrong.

also adding padding or margin doesnt really work.
[image]

my css:

```
.section-filters {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.sticky-filters {
  width: 100%;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

my code in react:

```
 <Section className="section-filters">
        <Box className="sticky-filters" mb="10">
          <Filters />
        </Box>

        <ProjectList projects={filtered} />
      </Section>
```

I also tried changing my code to:

```
<Section className="section-filters">
        <Box  sx{{
            width:1000,
            heigh:100

           }}
     className="sticky-filters" mb="10">
          <Filters />
        </Box>

        <ProjectList projects={filtered} />
      </Section>
```

And with this way, i get more width but only in thr right side. Im not using mui components, so I dont understand them really well right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 100vw inside your width css
Like this

```
width:100vw
```